# Why use @property for NSArrays in iOS

Tags: objective-c, properties

why would you use `@property` with `NSArray`?

The reason for my question is because I was under the impression that `@properties` were mainly used to take advantage of the **getter** and **setter** you get for free when you use `@property`, but when you assign an `NSArray` to a property you know you will never use the getter and setter to access the objects in the array, why use properties on this case. Does this have to do with **ARC**, in other words is this considered a better memory management practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use a property to get or set the whole array. You also use the property to access individual elements of the array.

Using a property with an array has nothing to do with ARC or MRC. Properties are a way to encapsulate data. That's it.

If you don't wish to provide access to the whole array then don't use a property. Add method(s) to set/get individual elements of the internal array if that is appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Along with what already said by other answers, I usually like to `copy` my array for security purposes.

If you're accepting an `NSArray` by the client, she could potentially provide you a `NSMutableArray` instance. If that's the case and you want to ensure that the array you're working with doesn't change unexpectedly, you'd better `copy` it as opposed to `retain` it.

Properties come in handy in this case since you can declare

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray * myArray;
```

and be sure that you're the only owner of that array after you assigned it.

I typically use this strategy for any class with mutable subclasses, such as `NSString`, `NSArray`, `NSSet` and so on, whenever I care about the ownership of the data.

The downside of this strategy is of course memory efficiency, but in the end engineering is the art of intelligent compromise.

Comment: And note that in the most common case, there is no memory cost, since `[NSArray copy]` is implemented effectively as `retain` (since its immutable). You only pay for the copy when you actually need it (because it's a mutable array).

Answer (score 2):

To use the array outside of a single method or class. ClassA.array = ClassB.array; or to simply read from the array in a different method of the same class since the array will dealloc immediately after execution.

Answer (score 2):

> but when you assign an NSArray to a property you know you will never
>   use the getter and setter to access the objects in the array, why use
>   properties on this case.

For the same reasons that you use properties for other objects:

- **accessors:** The accessors are for the array itself, not objects in the array. It's not uncommon to get or set an entire array at once:

  ```
  NSArray *kids = frank.children;                 // get the array
  mary.children = @[@"Nick", @"Sam", @"Susan"];   // set the array
  ```
- **abstraction:** Using properties instead of accessing the underlying array directly makes it easier to change the implementation later, should that become necessary.
- **KVC compliance:** You get it for free with properties. With collections like arrays, KVC gives you a lot of power. You can use collection operators like `@avg` and @`max` as well as indexed accessors:

  ```
  int employees = [accounting countOfEmployees];  // same as [accounting.employees count]
  Employee *thirdEmployee = [engineering objectInEmployeesAtIndex:2];  // same as [engineering.employees objectAtIndex:2]
  ```